# Linking to specific sections on a different page

Tags: html, hyperlink

My objective is to link to specific sections on merchandise.html from other html pages on the site, all of which have the relevant sending links set by a .dwt file, so the sending links are uniform on all sending pages. 
In Int Ex 11 this works fine, but not in Fire 75.0 or Chrome. In those browsers, the links take me to the source code of merchandise.html.
Example: Sending page (in top navigation bar):

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Merchandise</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="merchandise.html #apparel">Apparel and Accessories</a>
<a href="merchandise.html #dvd">DVD's</a>
<a href="merchandise.html #cd">CD's</a>
</div>
</li>
```

These are meant to link to the following markers in merchandise.html:

```
<h2 id=dvd>DVDs</h2>
<h2 id=cd>CDs</h2>
<h2 id=apparel>Apparel and Accessories</h2>
```

I repeat, this works fine in Int Ex 11 browser.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, you haven't met the minimum requirements for a post here. Please revise to show some markup demonstrating your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing mostly correct.

Removing the space between ".html" and "#" might do the job. A standard URI should not have that space. Such as `merchandise.html#apparel`.

Also, standard html tag attributes should have quotes around them. Such as `<h2 id="apparel">...</h2>`.

Comment: Please accept this answer by clicking that tick. Thanks!